# How do I use Rails.application.credentials.dig to load data to a storage.yml phrase?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

If I leave my cloudinary credentials in the clear in the storage.yml file my Ruby on Rails application works fine.  If I try to use the same data by calling for extraction from the secrets file, my program fails, asking for the api-key.

Below are two views of a stanza in my storage.yml file, the top (with cloudinary without the 'i') is the code that fails.    The second stanza (with the real my_xxx data instead of these placeholder) works fine.  Somehow I am messing up the credentials.dig function, but do not understand what I have wrong.  The credentials.yml.enc file has an exact replica of the second stanza with the correct credentials place below the master key.

cloudnary:

```
service: Cloudinary

cloud_name: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:cloudinary, :cloud_name) %>

api_key: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:cloudinary, :api_key) %>
api_secret: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:cloudinary, :api_secret) %>
```

cloudinary:

```
service: Cloudinary

cloud_name: my_cloud_name

api_key: my_cloudinary_api_key

api_secret: my_api_secret
```

I would expect to be able to use the credentials.yml.enc file to hold the cloudinary credentials.

Answer (score -2):

Found that if I take the ':cloudinary, ' from the ...dig(:cloudinary, :cloud_name) the dig operations returns the value correctly.  So the correct format for the storage.yml file is:

service: cloudinary

cloud_name: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:cloud_name) %>

api_key: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:api_key) %>

api_secret: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:api_secret) %>